# What apple device takes photos with a resolution of 2250px x 3000px?

Tags: iphone, ipad, photos

I'm trying to figure out what kind of mobile apple device took a certain photo that was sent to me, and I'm hoping you guys can help.  The dimensions of the photo are 2250px x 3000px.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you access the EXIF data attached to the photo?

Comment: @nohillside yes, but the only data shown was date created and size

Comment: @Jodast then in that case the photo has been modified since and the resolution isn't indicative of the original device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the photo was cropped because that image is 6.75 megabytes and i don't know of an Apple device with a 6.75 megapixel camera. The small camera on the new ipad pros are 2320 x 3088. it cold easily be a slightly cropped image from an ipad pro.

The main Camera on the ipad pro is about 12 megapixels or 4032 X 3024 = 12.192768 Megapixels. This could also easily be cropped to your size.

I don't know what sizes the newer iPhone cameras are but your probably looking foe a 7-meg camera or larger.

Answer (score 2):

If the photo you have wasn't modified, it should still contain the name of the device it was taken by in its EXIF data.

Right-click on the photo and choose 'Get Info':

[image: Right click on photo to get info]

Under the 'More info:' section, you will find the name of the device.

[image]

As a side note, the 2250 x 3000 resolution seems to be popular within graphic design (flyers, posters, etc). It corresponds to the minimum resolution in order to print on a 8.5" x 11" surface (US letter size) at 300dpi.